# Getting assignment without cast warning when I shouldn't?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, compiler-warnings

I'm writing a string split function.

So, the function is doing its job. At least for the tests I did.

But during the compile I get

> user/user_main.c:53:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast [enabled by default]   splt = str_split(&length,
>   pokusaj, ' ');

I don't understand what is the problem. Later in my code I use splt/length as I would normally and get the desired result. So, why am I getting this warning?
If I cast it, the warning disappears (obviously), but I don't want to cast it, the function returns what it returns so I shouldn't need to cast the result.

Code:

```
uint8_t** str_split(uint32_t* length, uint8_t* toSplit, uint8_t delimiter){
    uint8_t* curr = toSplit;
    uint8_t** poses = (uint8_t**) os_malloc(sizeof(uint8_t*)*STRTOK_MAX_LEN);
    uint32_t pos = 0;
    uint32_t len;
    uint8_t** dst;

    os_printf("String:--%s--\n", toSplit);

    while(pos < STRTOK_MAX_LEN) poses[pos++] = NULL;

    pos = 0;
    poses[pos++] = curr;
    curr++;
    while((curr = os_strchr(curr, delimiter) ) != NULL && pos < STRTOK_MAX_LEN){
        poses[pos++] = curr;
        curr++;
    }

    if(pos == 0) return 0;
    dst = (uint8_t**) os_malloc(sizeof(uint8_t*) * (pos));

    pos = 0;
    while(pos < STRTOK_MAX_LEN-1 && poses[pos] != NULL){
        if(poses[pos+1] != NULL){
            len = (poses[pos+1] - poses[pos]);
            if(poses[pos][0] == delimiter)
                len -= 1;
        }
        else{
            len = os_strlen(toSplit) - (poses[pos]-toSplit) - 1;    
        }

        if(len > 1){
            dst[pos] = (uint8_t*) os_malloc(len+1);
            os_memset(dst[pos], '\0', (len+1));
            if(poses[pos][0] == delimiter)
                os_memcpy(dst[pos], poses[pos]+1, len);
            else
                os_memcpy(dst[pos], poses[pos], len);
            os_printf("Length:%d\n", len);
            os_printf("Item:--%s--\n", dst[pos]);
        }
        else{
            dst[pos] = NULL;
        }

        pos++;
    }

    *length = pos;

    return dst;
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
uint32_t length = 0;
uint8_t** splt;
splt = str_split(&length, pokusaj, ' ');

os_printf("len=%d\n", length);
os_printf("splt=%u\n", splt);
uint32_t i;
for(i=0; i<length; i++){
    os_printf("printing %d\n", i);
    if(splt[i] != NULL) os_printf("splt[%d]=%s\n", i, splt[i]);
}
```

pokusaj:

```
#define pokusaj "NEKI string Koji je  Maximalno Random!  "
```

I intentionally didn't name the question

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled
>   by default]

because there already a lot of them. If this is a problem, please say and I will edit it accordingly.

Also, I'm primarily interested in why I get the warning. All suggestions about the code are appreciated (of course), but not necessary.

P.S. I wouldn't post this question normally (easy solution), but this bugs me GREATLY and I think I am missing something critical!

Comment: That's a very complicated *split* function, you should really think about rewriting it.

Comment: Are there any other warnings?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I know, but not much time to think about it. No other warnings. Tried to find source code for it, but couldn't. I don't have most of C functions (working on espressif). This does the job, and won't be called so often, so I guess it's ok. Only time will tell though.

Comment: I would check that *it does the job* without causing undefined behavior. You need a memory debugger for that.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to free "poses". Now no memory leaks.

Btw no debugger setup (espressif chip) and no time to set it up.

Comment: Don't write code if you don't have time. That's crazy, a bug could explode later causing tragedies.

Comment: Haha, well I have deadlines and have to meet them. But this isn't so much related to the question P: Everyone has their own philosophy. Yeah, it's better to write quality code, but sometimes that isn't an option.

Comment: which line is #57?

Comment: a modest 2-3 lines of setup, then a 3-4 line loop that uses `strtok()` to break out each part of the input would be much better (and clearer).  No need to `malloc()` each entry in the **dest, just use `strdup()` and use `realloc()` to expand the size of `dest`, as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types do match in the both the function call and what the function returns.
So, I believe the reason for that warning message is you haven't provided a prototype or declaration for `str_split()` function. Or, at least it's not available when you make the call to `str_split()`.

As a result, the compiler assumes `str_split()` returns `int` (which is an outdated convention. *Implicit function declaration* is not valid in C since [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)).

Add a prototype at the top of the source file:

```
uint8_t** str_split(uint32_t* length, uint8_t* toSplit, uint8_t delimiter);
```

Alternatively, you can make a [header file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive#C.2FC.2B.2B) and include it in your source files. This is preferred in case the function `str_split()` is used/called in multiple source files.

Comment: That's it. I forgot to include the header S: Silly me. Thank you.

Comment: Detecting such errors is easier with `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration` compiler option added (GCC) - I never compile C code without...

Comment: Good point. Will see to it when I have the time. Breaking all deadlines ):